# Запись квадрата из чисел в файл(многопоточность)

Tags: java, многопоточность

Дали задание записать в файл квадрат из чисел используя многопоточность. Квадрат вот такого формата:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
...
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

запись проводить посимвольно, по очереди каждым потоком. Я наваял что-то подобное:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("someFile.txt","rw");
        FileController fc;
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            fc = new FileController(i, file);
            fc.run();
        }
    }
```

Класс FileController:

```
class FileController extends Thread{

    int number;
    RandomAccessFile raf;
    StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();

    FileController(int number, RandomAccessFile raf){
        this.number = number;
        this.raf = raf;
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        controller();
    }

    public synchronized void controller() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                raf.seek((long) number);
                line.toString().replaceAll("\n", "");
                line.append(number);
                line.append(" ");
                line.append("\n");
                System.out.println(line);
                raf.write(line.toString().getBytes());
                try {
                    sleep(500);
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но работает не так как нужно. И чисел больше записывает чем нужно, и не линиями. Что не так делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут много чего. Надо переписывать.

По сути:

1. [`Thread.run`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run--) вызывает метод `run` в текущем потоке. Для того чтобы запустить отдельный поток используйте [`Thread.start`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--). В коде `start` вызывается в конструкторе. Т.е. все потоки запустятся параллельно и вместе с этим в основном потоке они запустятся синхронно.
2. [`RandomAccessFile.seek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek(long)) устанавивает текущую позицию в байтах от начала файла. Соответственно, `seek(number)` не установит позицию ни в строку № `number` ни в позицию № `number`. С учетом пробелов и переносов строк положение скорее всего будет неожиданным.
   Есть еще проблема в самой концепции. Подход «каждый поток рассчитает свою позицию в файле и независимо от других туда запишет» не соответствует заданию по которому потоки должны взаимодействовать друг с другом, чтобы писать по очереди. С этим связан следующий пункт.
3. Механизма взаимодействия потоков в коде нет. Его нужно будет написать. Поищите в интернете по ключевым словам «java синхронизация потоков».

По мелочи:

4. Поле `line` используется только в одном методе. Проще будет сделать его локальной переменной. Смысла использовать `StringBuffer` вместо `String` тоже нет.
5. `int` к `long` приводить не надо: `raf.seek(number);`
6. Перенос строки почему-то добавляется к каждому числу.

Отладка многопоточных приложений в общем случае — тема сложная, но есть универсальные принципы для отладки вообще, которые могут пригодиться:

7. Если не получилось вывести десять строк попробуйте вывести одну/две.
8. Если программа не работает с десятью потоками проверьте работает ли она как ожидается с одним/двумя.
9. Если не работают десять строк кода, протестируйте что каждая из них работает как ожидается в изоляции.
10. Примитивный прием выводить в консоль каждую строку кода и поток:

    ```
    ...
    System.out.println("Thread "+number+": raf.seek((long) number);");
    raf.seek((long) number);
    System.out.println("Thread "+number+": line.toString().replaceAll(...");
    line.toString().replaceAll("\n", "");
    ...
    ```

    поможет отловить простые ошибки.

Так будет меньше путаницы и накладок. Можно будет задавать более точные вопросы вида «Почему поток запустился два раза, а не один?» или «Почему число записывается не в ту строку?». На такие вопросы можно будет получить более точные и быстрые ответы.

Comment: спасибо. Очень подробно и понятно. Буду пошагово использовать данный, так сказать, мануальчик=))))))))